# Low memory message on Windows 7 SP1

Tags: windows-7, memory, commit-charge

I have a big problem with a computer that is getting a Low memory message. The specifications of this computer are:

- Windows 7 SP1
- 32-bit Operating System
- 4 GB RAM

The computer is getting the following message every 4 or 5 days:

***Your computer is low on memory***
*To restore enough memory for programs to work correctly, save your files and then close or restart all open programs.*

After this message appears the computer starts to run very slow and we need to restart it. The problem is that the computer it’s in a production environment and has to monitories the activity of a PLC constantly.
The actions that we did trying to fix this memory problem but without success are:

- Stop all the applications that use a high volume of memory (SQL Server, Wonderware InTouch HMI SCADA, Reporting Services, VMWare)
- Reinstall the operative system and all the software.
- Scan for a virus issue without success.

Checking the event viewer we found the following suspects messages:

- Application log

*Warning*: PerfDisk; Unable to read performance data for the Disk performance counters.

- System log

*Warning*: Windows successfully diagnosed a low virtual memory condition. The following programs consumed the most virtual memory: view.exe (4560) consumed 37871616 bytes, DASSIDirect.exe (2904) consumed 21807104 bytes, and perfmon.exe (5868) consumed 18018304 bytes.

*Error*: The Vstor2 P2V30 Virtual Storage Driver service failed to start due to the following error: The system cannot find the path specified.

Checking the memory used in Resource Monitor window we found that the Commit charge increases constantly till arrives to 100% aprox. And the Memory Modified increase the same way. The Memory in Use stays at the values 1GB aprox.

This Commit charge increase is normal? It doesn’t have to decrease when internal processes are finished

Comment: Your problem is low virtual memory. Commit charge is physical memory. Likely one has nothing to do with the other. What's your page file size?

Comment: Your options are increase your page file significantly, or switch to a 64 bit OS and get more RAM.


For a computer in a production setting, 4GB of RAM simply doesn't cut it anymore.

Comment: Committed memory and modified memory increasing together could mean pagefile is to small. Check paged and non paged pool sizes in Task Manager as well.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to explain that we increase the page file to 4GB and we still have the same problem. Also we are configuring a 64 bits additional computer in case we cannot fix this problem in the original one. Thank you very much for responding so quick

Comment: Dear all, 
Sorry for answering so late but in production status the availability of the machine is not so flexible as we want.
So this is the current situation:
- We already install a completely new computer with 64 bits OS version and exactly the same software than the previous 32 bits OS version.
- We increase the page file to 4GB

With this configuration we still seeing that the modified memory increase at very high values (3,7GB aprox.) .
Could it be a virus infection?

Answer (score 1):

Virtual memory is pagefile, increase your pagefile size and see if it makes a difference. It should solve your problem. You are running out of virtual memory, so closing programs frees this up, as would rebooting.

Basically virtual memory works like RAM by using part of your storage space. So when RAM runs low, virtual memory moves data from RAM to an allocated space on your hard drive called paging file. Where it is then available as if it were also RAM.

On windows 7 sp1 there are a few ways to access the virtual memory settings.
Here is a link explaining how [Click me](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/change-virtual-memory-size)

Comment: Please expand your answer for clarity... :)

Comment: First of all thanks for your answer. We increased the pagefile size before I open this post. We saw yesterday afternoon that if we close any process on task manager the Memory Modified decrease but the value keeps very high. To be precise it was 1318 MB and when we close a few processes it decrease to 1010 MB.

Comment: how much did you increase it?

Comment: We increse it to 4GB